# The java interface ExecutorService has several submit methods which accept Runnable or Callable task as parameter. Can I pass an object method?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

The interface `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` has several `submit` methods,[image: submit]
The second one accept a `Runnable` task parameter. However, I saw some code like this, first is the `Counter` class:

```
public class Counter {
    private int count;
    public void increment() {
        count++;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

and the `Demo` class:

```
public class Demo {
    private Counter counter = new Counter();
    public void demoCounter() {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        IntStream.range(0, 1000)
            forEach(i -> service.submit(counter:: increment));
        service.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Counter count=" + counter.getCount());
    }
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.demoCounter();
    }
}
```

What I wonder is that in the `Demo` class, the submit method's parameter is `counter:: increment` which I think is not a `Runnable` task Object. So, was there something magic happened?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: And this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing

Comment: I understand.Thank you!@JBNizet@Seelenvirtuose

Comment: But note that this code example is broken as the `increment()` method  is not thread safe and this code lets multiple threads call it the on the same object.